# Codeigniter model not saving on database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an application that should save every transaction on my database. The controller code goes like this:

```
$info = array(
    'student_id' => $this->user['id'],
    'transaction_id' => $ref,
    'value' => $amount,
    'final_value' => $final_value,
    'payment_status' => '0',
    'date' => date('Y-m-d'),
  );

$this->load->model('student_model');
if($this->student_model->insertPurchaseForStudent($info)){

  // Some other code here 

}
```

And this is my model ('student_model'):

```
public function insertPurchaseForStudent($info){
  if($this->db->insert('compra', $this->db->escape($info))){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

I'm having an enormous headache because some transactions are saved on the database and others are not. I thought it could be some kind of instability on my database servers, so I've added a *for loop*, to try more than once, and to log an error message if it's not able to save:

```
$i = 1;
for ($i == 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  if($this->student_model->insertPurchaseForStudent($info)){

    // to leave the loop
    $i = 7;

    // Some other code here 

  }else{
    sleep(3);
    switch($i){
      case 2 :
        log_message('error', 'Second attempt to add transaction');
      break;
      case 3 :
        log_message('error', 'Third attempt to add transaction');
      break;
      case 4 :  
        log_message('error', 'Fourth attempt to add transaction');
      break;
      case 5 :
        log_message('error', 'Fifth attempt to add transaction');
      break;
      case 6 :
        log_message('error', 'Sixth attempt, giving up');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, when it does not save the transaction, I don't see any messages on my error log.

I'd be really grateful with any ideas of what's the possible cause, or where am I slipping in this code I wrote.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry @quantme, $info is an array with the transaction information. I've updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: `$this->user['id']` comes from a previous/current database operation or from a session?

Comment: I tried to replicate error, none yet. If you still have the problem you must provide more info (code).

Comment: @quantme, thanks for the help. `$this->user['id']` comes from a session:     `$this->data['user'] = $this->user = $this->session->userdata('user');`

Comment: What [driver](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers) do you use for your session?

Comment: What are the basic requirements of your system? I could do some basic code to try something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to thank everyone who helped me with this.

I've finally found the problem. And it's lame, I'm sorry.

The model and the controller were all good. They were saving the transaction in my DB.

But I have a badly named function '*courseForStudentCheck()*' that not only checks if the student is enrolled, but also deletes it from my DB. I need that for some cases, but I should've named it in a different way, because inadvertently I started using it just to check if a user was enrolled. And that's where the problem started.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$this->db->set($data)` like this:

```
public function insertPurchaseForStudent($info){
  $this->db->set($info);
  if($this->db->insert('compra'){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can find more example using `set()` in [CodeIgniter Manual Inserting Data](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

See if it works.

Comment: Thanks @MSI, I'm deploying this fix and I'll update the question if it happens again.